# Prototype Request Ajax.Updater Security/authentication for every request

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs, validation

My website Contains Prototype Framework and programmed in PHP. (i know very very basic javascript)

**Website Normal Visitor & Its Actions**

*Some what similar to keepvid .com*

A)It have one Input box where user put link and than press submit. (?var=userfoo execute via prototype frame work) (the request is send to same page action=index.php)

B)It shows Loading gif than it display the result in  by default it is hidden and show on request.

C)Now The parent window html (Main Page) isn't refreshed or reloaded.

D)User Again Put link and press submit it does the same a b c process.

Every thing was working fien but i come to notice problem while checking logs.
Some was using scripts to grab my output. Not normal visitor you can say or leechers.

**Problem :**

1)But if some one put http:// url?var=foo&var=bar in the browser it will generate the output content  of div that means no main page visit. anyone can pass query and directly get the result.

2) I tried using Session Token But it fails as it regenerate in div. also the parent is not refreshed so the session token doesn't match (THIS ONLY HAPPENS WITH AJAX REQUEST 1 request is giving output okay but the second request fails as the parent token is same. And submit button uses the same token) On pure PHP it works it refresh the page but i don't want to refresh the page. I just want to show loading gif.

3)Any one can use curl php and grab the page. So i wanted a Javascript verification (HIDDEN). If fails than Start Captcha in short if Javascript is disabled than start captcha security. I don't want to make it work on verbose or through command line or through another script (for fetching).

4) I don't know exactly what the things are called. I think they are XHR.

**I want to Provide Security for my website from**

1)URL Variable Injection like 
?var=foo&&var2=bar
but also allow to convert (if some body does that ) to divert the page to
?redirect=foo and load mainpage and put that redirect value to input box

2) Server Based Verification but inside the div and must show loading gif and donot reload the entire page..

**Things i looked but failed...**

1) JCryption but it needs Jquery than i have to recode everything...

2)

```
// If the request did not come from AJAX, exit:
          if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !='XMLHttpRequest'){
          exit;
          }
```

This command fails with IE7 browser. (this is the ONLY BEST METHOD BUT FAILS IN JUST ONE BROWSER) Also one more problem is If some one create  run it on the local host change the action to http://myurl than it will still accept it. Also if we make a curl to send custom header than it will defeat the purpose.

3) Used JavaScript Encryption and PHP Decryption. SOME JS to enrypt and php function to decrypt. (through using Hidden form element input)
This was also a good method but i am having difficulty in editing the source to pass variable i mean from div to server.

Also used few other method but i think that all that above methods are the best to describe me problem...
Kindly understand that the solution might be very small or big but i don't understand JavaScript much so kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

- Generate a random value and store it in a session variable.

  ```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['nonce'] = base64_encode(md5(mt_rand()));
  ```
- Use that value as a hidden element in the form, or add it to the AJAX URL as a parameter.

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nonce'] ?>"/>
  ```
- Compare the value stored in session with the value requested by AJAX. If it fails inform the browser with a 403 error.

  ```
  session_start();
  if ($_GET['nonce'] !== $_SESSION['nonce']) {
      header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
      die('Forbidden. Please check your cookies and try again.');
  }
  ```
- Only update the page on success.

  ```
  new Ajax.Updater({success: 'ELEMENT ID'}, 'AJAX URL');
  ```
- If an error is detected the updater fails and no change is made.

Comment: or add it to the AJAX URL as a parameter ?

Comment: An URL query parameter is like `?nonce=randomvalue`

Comment: Thx for the fast reply but how to store the session value (are u talking abt php session?).. so it will become PHP pass session var to javascript ?

Comment: I've added some more detail to my examples.

Comment: I Will check the above said example and report back today it self

Comment: I done some testing and final what i did is made this system index will not contain the session or any other code now i made changes and now everything will be done through ajaxrequest and ajaxupdater. what ajaxrequest will do is request for a token from token.php after getting the output store to var pass that var to ajaxupdater than it will send that to processor.php which will validate and process the request. everything is fien. just little smallest problems are there. but will report tommorow. What u think abt this ? (i will also post code tommorow) was learning prototype whole day basic.

Comment: @cloclworkgeek now index.php will not contain anything just the input box and the ajax
Index.php (contains the ajaxRequest and ajaxUpdater)
token.php (Generate the nounce and set it to $_session['nounce'])
processor.php (verify the nounce value via $_session and nounce value)
a) Ajax (AjaxRequest)send request to get token from token.php
b) Ajax get the token and store it Javascript var.
c) Ajax (AjaxUpdater) send the url and stored token to processor
d) Processor.php checks the token if valid it will process the link else ajax updater will execute onfailure (cont)

Comment: @cloclworkgeek (cont)
Problem with this is that i think it will only generate session for mywebsite like this
Mywebsite sending ajaxRequest so it means mywebsite will generate session not the visitor ? I am confused.
If multiple user access request at the same time it will give error or what does it actually work on client/visitor side?session i mean.

Comment: Sessions are particular to individual users so it cannot confuse different requests at the same time.

Comment: @clockworkgeek I would also like to know that if i turn off cookie the site will not work. Is it possible to make it work if the cookies are off?

Comment: It can be done with [session passing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).